# Is smart watch illegal while in control of the vehicle?

Tags: united-kingdom, is-x-legal, driving, phone

From the gov.uk website:

> It’s illegal to hold and use a phone, sat nav, tablet, or any device
> that can send or receive data, while driving or riding a motorcycle.

A smartwatch can send or receive data. It is on the driver's wrist. Is it legal?

Comment: It would be illegal to hold and use a smartwatch in your hand. You don't hold a smartwatch on your wrist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It says hold **and use**. Having a smartphone in your backpack is fine. Having a smartwatch on your wrist is fine. Using the smart watch for a phone call or a game or whatever while driving is not.

Comment: Then checking the time is illegal too.

Comment: @Why would you need to? Don't all cars have a clock somewhere on the dashboard?

Comment: But you don't _hold_ a smartwatch at all. You _wear_ a smartwatch.

Comment: @0___________ It is, depending on how charitable you think the police and judge would be. By law, it's illegal. By common sense, it's not. FWIW I do not think the UK law enforcement are unbiased.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff nearly all; some of them even show the right time! Mine's still on BST because I only change it when I fill up with fuel and reset the trip meter deliberately as I tend to do it accidentally when setting the clock.  It also keep dreadful time

Comment: @ChrisH, (warning: off-topic) yes car clocks are terrible.  My car receives at least three data streams with time information (RDS, DAB and GPS), yet leaves the clock drifting, and doesn't correct it for the daylight-saving transition.  Very disappointing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having trouble finding one page with the most up to date version of "Road Vehicles Regulations" with all amendments included, but the [important amendment for this question is from 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2003/2695/made).  Revisions to sections 4 and 6 were made in [2022](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2022/81/made), I've included the updated language in brackets.

> “Mobile telephones
> 110.—(1) No person shall drive a motor vehicle on a road if he is using—
>
> (a)a hand-held mobile telephone; or (b)a hand-held device of a kind
> specified in paragraph (4).

> (4) A device referred to in paragraphs (1)(b), (2)(b) and (3)(b) is a
> device, other than a two-way radio, which [is capable of transmitting
> and receiving data, whether or not those capabilities are enabled.]

> (6) For the purposes of this regulation—
> (a)a mobile telephone or other device is to be treated as hand-held if
> it is, or must be, held at some point [while being used] ;

A smart watch definitely falls into the category of interactive devices in paragraph 4, so the question is whether you "hold" a smart watch while using it.  The plain English answer would of course be no, you normally wear a watch while using it rather than holding it.  That doesn't necessarily mean that a court hasn't interpreted "hold" under a definition that includes a wearing smart watch though, don't take this as legal advice.

Comment: How hard would it be for legislators to specify that it's illegal to use such devices in any manner that might plausibly impair the safe operation of a motor vehicle, specifying that use of such devices would be *presumed* unsafe unless shown to be safe?  Someone who glances at a smart watch simply to check the time could probably argue successfully that such usage was of such a fleeting nature as to not pose a hazard, but such arguments would be less successful when applied to more substantive tasks.

Comment: @supercat I was considering that, it seems like it would be easy enough to borrow the language for DUI based on visible impairment.  Something like "voluntarily distracted sufficient to impair their ability to drive safely."  This would also have the advantage of covering other forms of voluntary distraction like looking in the mirror.

Comment: @supercat, we didn't have laws against looking at your wristwatch before "smart" watches, we don't need them now.

Comment: @MichaelHall that line of reasoning is entirely unconvincing.  Wristwatches don't offer their users the ability to read paragraphs of text (among other actions that take far more time and attention than checking the time on a wristwatch).  A smartwatch has the potential to distract a driver much more significantly than a wristwatch can.

Comment: There's actually two definitional questions: whether you "hold" it (as you say) _and_ whether simply wearing it counts as "using".  I would claim that it's not using until you start operating it (by pressing buttons, or talking to it, or whatever).  But if it has a scrolling or otherwise changing display, then we might expect that staring at it waiting for information constitutes a sufficient distraction from the road for a court to consider that "using".

Comment: @phoog: If a driver who was near a public digital clock were to focus on a wristwatch to see whether it advanced the minute before or after the public clock, and were to rear-end someone for doing so, I would such a situation should be viewed similarly to someone who was focusing on a phone or other device.  Actually, I think visual readouts are probably less distracting than text-to-speech systems, because they allow a driver to quickly glance at a text and ascertain whether it merits a "yes" response, a "no" response, or an "I'll get back to you later", and ascertain whether it's...

Comment: ...worth stopping for.  Most messages a driver might receive should be dealt with when the driver reaches the destination, but if a driver can receive a message like "Meeting canceled" while en route, that may be far more useful than having the driver get to what would have been the meeting site before reading about the cancellation.

Comment: @phoog, notice that I didn't make any statements about the relative difference in volume of data available on smart watches, I said we don't need specific laws banning a driver from glancing at them.  Back in the day if I was distracted changing out an 8 track tape and caused an accident I would have been at fault, but that didn't create a cry for legislators to ban touching your 8 track tape.  We need less distracted driving, not more technology specific regulations.